# comint with serial-term

Tags: shell, emacs

OK I love comint mode in emacs, however I do have a problem.

I need to communicate with an embedded Linux board through a serial line.

There are two ways I have been able to do this:

1) I basically can set up a putty serial session ( Specifying serial dev, baud rate, etc, etc. ), save the session,  and then inside of emacs( both in Linux, and in Windows), from the shell I invoke plink "saved putty session name". This works great for comint. I can use my key bindings to access my history relatively well. The one thing I lose with this method is  command completion.

I believe I lose this because the line is not sent to the serial device until a line termination is detected. A tab, not being considered a line termination just sits on the buffer awaiting to be sent. I have attempted to solve this problem by binding the  character to the "comint-send-input" function but so far this has not worked for me.

2) 
I know I can use "serial-term" to bypass putty and have tab expansion in raw input mode, however in doing so I lose the ability to use my history bindings.

I want both. I want to be able to use the history as I would on a shell and at the same time I would like to have tab completion on the serial target as I get when using raw character mode in the "serial-terminal". Any  help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `term-mode`?